# nested string argument in template

Tags: angular

When I have key argument as:

```
const arg = 'name';
```

I can do this in html template:

```
{{object[arg]}}
```

But what if I have nested object and argument like this:

```
const arg = 'profile.name';
```

Can I pass this arg in html template?

Comment: _Can I pass this arg in html template?_ - Did you try?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this in that way. but you can do

```
 {{ object['profile']['name'] }}
```

which means you need to split your string from . (dot) and give it in the way that i do

```
 {{ object[arg[0]][arg[1]] }}
```

you can write helper function to achieve this result with more generic way.